# Combinatorics Question, at least n items must be chosen: two different thinking approaches are used but second one does not work.

Tags: combinatorics

Question: There are 10 apples and 15 bananas. Find the number of ways to choose 6 fruits if 3 apples must be chosen. (Assume all fruits are distinct)

This question confused me a lot:

The correct approach is to calculate by choosing 3, 4, 5 and 6 apples respectively:
${10 \choose 3}{15 \choose 3}$$+$${10 \choose 4}{15 \choose 2}$$+$${10 \choose 5}{15 \choose 1}$$+$${10 \choose 6}{15 \choose 0}$$=$$80640$

My second thought is that we can choose 3 apples then choose 3 fruits from the remaining. Unfortunately, this approach gives **an incorrect result**:
${10 \choose 3}{(10-3+15) \choose 3}$$=$${10 \choose 3}{22 \choose 3}$$=$$184800$ which is significantly larger than the correct answer.

What confused me is that how and where the error comes from in the second approach? And is there any ways to subtract/divide  something from the second approach to get the correct answer? Thanks in advance for answering this question.

Comment: The second approach overcounts whenever there are more than 3 apples. E.g., if apples 1,2,3 are chosen, then apple 4 and bananas 1 and 2, this is the same choice as apples 1,2,4 chosen then apple 3 and bananas 1 and 2. But the second method counts them as separate.

Answer (score 2):

To see that your second approach is wrong consider collection of fruits that contains 4 apples a1..a4 Each apple can be selected among the first 3 apples and among the last 22 fruits. Your second approach counts these 4 cases as distinct collections of fruits, though really they are the same collection of 4 apples and 2 bananas.

I don't see a simple way to correct the second approach.

Comment: The overcounting is not uniform -- it is by a  factor of $C(k,3)$ for the case of choosing $k$ apples altogether (for $k=4,5,6$), so indeed there is no simple way to get from the total $184800$ to the correct value without breaking down into the cases for $k$.

Comment: I understand now, thank you. If there is no way to amend the second approach, is there a general formula to solve for the number ways of a As and b Bs with at least n As?

Comment: @VitalsBat The only general formula is a summation. If you want to choose $k$ fruits, with at least $n$ apples, the number of ways is $\binom{a}{n}\binom{b}{k-n}+\binom{a}{n+1}\binom{b}{k-1}+\dots+\binom{a}{k}\binom{b}0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt is incorrect because you have *fractionated* the selection by first choosing three apples, and then choosing the remaining fruits any which way. But this means that you are choosing an unknown number of distinct apples already chosen the first time an unknown number of times, and thus overcounting.

I don't know any way to sort out the unholy mess that the second method is. Stick to the straight and narrow !